# PHP IDE with vi key bindings

Tags: php, vim, ide

At the moment I'm using eclipse with viplugin. I also know about netbeans and its vi plugin.
I find both of these IDEs don't really fit my tastes though. Too slow, bad remote editing support. I don't really have time at the moment to set up and try a vim based ide either.

So, what other PHP IDE is available that supports vi key bindings? I'm willing to pay for a commercial one if necessary.

Comment: My coworkers still use vim for all of their php work. What features are you looking for in an IDE that is not offered in vim?

Comment: I don't really have time at the moment to set up and try a vim based ide. I have a feeling it will take a while getting everything put together, and I have doubts that it will satisfy my desire for automatic completion, intellisense and the like. (I know it has key based completion at least)

Comment: There's not much setup at all. syntax on, filetype on, and run ctags on your code... and you're pretty much golden. Just add to your .vimrc as necessary. Don't worry about making everything perfect right away.

Answer (score 7):

I personnaly use [netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) with [jvi plugin](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/). The vi emulation of this vi plugin is near perfect, plus you get the very good (and fast growing) Netbeans Ide.

Comment: Same here, works good. Has some minor issues, but overall a great asset.

Answer (score 3):

I too would be curious as to why VIM is not an option for you.  If you have reason to rule it out, that's fair enough - but if not then I'd encourage you to think again about it.

I am a PHP programmer and I currently use VIM as my IDE.

- Fast (very!)
- VI key bindings come standard, no setting up necessary
- Various options for remote file editing

And yeah you still get the omni-completion, file explorer, smart auto-indenting, it's cross platform, etc etc.

Comment: I'm a sucker for nifty automatic intellisense, completion and the like. How similar is it in a vim setup?

Comment: vim 7 has omni-completion which is a smart form of autocompletion.  I am not a an auto-completion type of person so I don't know much about it.  You might need to try it out for yourself.

Comment: There's this PIV plugin for Vim that is for PHP development. To quickly check if Vim is something you might like I'd recommend that you can start with spf13 which is a collection of plugins and settings for Vim. It contains PIV. Also you can google for Vim as PHP IDE to get a good idea of what to expect and if you get even remote feeling that it might be good choice to go with Vim I'd give it a try. Just don't be put off by some initial annoyances.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that PHPStorm (paid) from JetBrains has a plugin that will make the editor simulate Vim.
The IDE is build on a common base for many of JetBrain's IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA, WebStorm, PyCharm, RubyMine and plugins are shared between them.

Also I would expect the IDE to be pretty good as I have some of their products and I'm very happy with them (JetBrains make good stuff).
I'm not doing PHP anymore so can't speak about the PHPStorm itself, but I'd recommend you give it a try if you can afford it.

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?webide&id=164

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) (free) from [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/). There is also [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) but that's about $250. It supports a bunch of dynamic languages (JavaScript, Perl, PHP, Python, etc) and has Vi and Emacs key-bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has a vi emulator (http://www.viemu.com) available for it.

I'm not sure how well Visual Studio works as an IDE for PHP though.  But it's a good IDE in general.

Comment: ViEmu is great (highly recommended) but Visual Studio isn't a PHP IDE, there's some "plugin" to make it work with PHP but I doubt that would be the right direction for a PHP coder. A better choice is to start with an IDE that natively speaks PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [vimmate](http://vimmate.rubyforge.org/). I am going to today.